# Compiz problems in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: compiz, 12.10, 64-bit

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 x64 on my notebook and I wanted to make a little customization in the UI, so i downloaded Compiz Settings Manager and opened it up. 
Once I opened it up, I found out that in the compiz are not all those settings and animations (that I could apply like on the photos, videos etc.) so I reinstalled it few times.

---

Once I get bored with the reinstalling I checked one field in there and Ubuntu (OS) started to get "lagged" (Dash get hid, OS started to do not respond very well).
So please, can anyone help me? How can I customize my ubuntu without get lagged and with all the animations that have to be available in the compiz? 
Thanks to all!

---

thank you! 
It seems that it helped to fix the Dash-hide problem, but I still do not have all the animations and features that have to be in the Compiz (program). Can you help me with this too please? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can install Gnome Shell:

1. [Download it here!](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/misc/promo-usb/GNOME-3.6.0.iso)

2.If you have a USB or DVD then plug that in!

3. Do the installation.
4. After the installation, Install CompizConfig Settings Again!

After that, you're done!

Comment: Your welcome! I'm glad that I helped